# RSpec puts different from should equal value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I cannot understand why the block of code below is not passing even though the puts value is showing the value I am checking for:

```
  let(:new_on_each_example) { MovieList.new }
  it "can use method defined by 'let'" do
    new_on_each_example.should_not be_nil
    # the object is memoized, so
    new_on_each_example.should == new_on_each_example

    puts new_on_each_example.class
    new_on_each_example.class.should == "MovieList"
  end
```

The console shows:

> MovieList
>
> expected: "MovieList"
>        got: MovieList(id: integer, title: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, track_number: integer) (using ==)

Puts displays the value that I'm looking for but the test fails. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_on_each_example.should be_instance_of(MovieList)
```

more info in [rspec matchers doc](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing to RSpec `"MovieList"`. It's a string, not the constant for your class. So you should do something like:

```
new_on_each_example.class.should == MovieList
```

but using RSpec you can do something more elegant too:

```
new_on_each_example.class.should be_a(MovieList)
```